# Android Studio: use one version number for all modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm building a complex project with multiple modules that gets build together to create a distributed sdk. 
My purpose is to have one variable for version major, minor and revision who I later inject into the buildConfig. 
Cant find how to do it.

This is what I tried so far:

```
project1: 
// PROJECT VERSIONS
project.ext {
    major = 1
    minor = 7
    revision = 2
}



project2:
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode project(':project1').ext.major 
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure these values in the `build.gradle` file in the root of the project.

Example:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

Then in the `module/build.gradle` you can use:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion  rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion  rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of `build.gradle` of `project2` add the following line:

```
evaluationDependsOn(':project1')
```

Then the evaluation you wrote will work.